# crm 2011 too many audit records

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, audit

Every time we create an Opportunity the following happens:

1. Each contact associated to opportunity's account gets audit record that looks like this: 
   [image]
2. Account associated to opportunity receives an audit record for each contact. That means if the account associated with an opportunity has 10 contacts, there are 10 audit records created for the account. Audit records looks like this: 
   [image]

Does anyone know why these audit records are being created and how to stop the system from creating them?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot stop this capturing because the entity is audit enabled. But there's no data to be captured for that instance. If you have atleast one attribute with audit enabled in that particular transaction, this will have data with sense.

For ex. This will happen on auditing Update/Associate message on any record, but when the lookup field is audit **disabled**.

[image]